# How do I add ASP.NET Identity tables in my database?

Tags: asp.net-identity

How do I add Asp.net Identity tables such as

```
AspNetUsers
AspNetRoles
```

into my existing database?

I use VS Express 2013 for Web and SQL Server 2008. I ran

```
aspnet_regsql.exe
```

located under

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
```

but it generated a bunch of tables that are for the old membership such as

```
aspnet_Users
aspnet_Roles
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out. may helpful for others. Here is how:

1. In web.config, replace DefaultConnection string with my own connection string AuburnConnection:

from

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication4-20140129022205.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication4-20140129022205;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to

```
<add name="AuburnConnection" connectionString="Data Source=COLADT014\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Auburn;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

2. In IdentityModels.cs, replace "DefaultConnection" with "AuburnConnection":

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext()
           : base("DefaultConnection")
       {
       }
   }
   ```

with

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("AuburnConnection")
        {
        }
    }
```

3. Run application and register a user.
4. All those asp.net Identity tables appear in your database.

Comment: Martial, did you already have a table built? I'm not getting this to work

Comment: Yes, just follow above 4 steps and it works. You cannot use aspnet_regsql.exe tool, that's for old version. Make sure your connection string is correct as in step 1 (with your own server and db of course).